# How do I export XMLHttpRequest result in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
function foo(callback) {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
          if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
              callback(httpRequest.responseText); // we're calling our method
          }
      }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', "http://size.ir/restapi/get_config");
  httpRequest.send();
}

  foo(function (result) {return (result+"*") });
```

here   is my code , and work well , how do I export the  result to . other js file ?

thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of `result+"*"`?

Comment: *  is . nothing I just expert this to . other js in reactnative  ,

Comment: @dsp_099 . * is . nothing I just expert this to . other js in reactnative  could you please help ?

Comment: What is it that you need to export? Do you need to export `foo`?

Comment: @dsp_099 I just  want to export my web json as json objecct to  other  js file  ...could you help me please ?

Comment: @dsp_099 Dear dsp_099  its possible to export that JSON and use it on other file without .then() block ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a stab at answering your question. I think you're asking if it's possible to do something like:

```
function foo(callback) {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) { // request is done
          if (httpRequest.status === 200) { // successfully
              callback(httpRequest.responseText); // we're calling our method
          }
      }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', "http://size.ir/restapi/get_config");
  httpRequest.send();
}

foo((jsonData) => {
  export jsonData; // not gonna work
})
```

And the answer is you can't. `import`/`export` needs to know *what* it is you're exporting first.

You can export a variable or constant but that constants needs to be set like:

```
const someValue = 123;
export default someValue;
```

You can also export the method itself:

```
export foo;
```

That being said I am concerned that you say you can't use then. Why not? You're doing something wrong if you're unable to use that or just a raw callback.

Comment: thank you very much , but I export foo like this :   export const foo = ((jsonData) => {
     return jsonData; }) and export must be in the top  block , and the in other js when I import foo , nothing return ! console.log(foo()); @dsp_099